# Processing xml with Power M

Tags: xml, powerbi, powerquery

I am struggling with transforming xml message to table view. Was searching for it, found few solutions, none of those worked or I implemented those poorly. Kindly asking for assistance how to build Power Query M code.

Xml message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query-response>
  <data-table filter="EXAMPLE" count="2">
    <columns>
      <column>Column01</column>
      <column>Column02</column>
      <column>Column03</column>
      <column>Column04</column>
      <column>Column05</column>
      <column>Column06</column>
      <column>Column07</column>
      <column>Column08</column>
      <column>Column09</column>
      <column>Column10</column>
      <column>Column11</column>
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row primary-key="4844496486">
        <field>aa</field>
        <field />
        <field>3</field>
        <field />
        <field />
        <field>OK</field>
        <field>+4589729222</field>
        <field>testmail01@test.com</field>
        <field />
        <field />
        <field>Active</field>
      </row>
      <row primary-key="4668781123">
        <field>aa  bbbbb</field>
        <field>AAAAAAAAAAA</field>
        <field>A</field>
        <field />
        <field />
        <field>OK</field>
        <field>+123439843933</field>
        <field>testmail01@test.com</field>
        <field>CT</field>
        <field>false</field>
        <field>Active</field>
      </row>
    </rows>
  </data-table>
</query-response>
```

The result of action taken in PowerBI (PowerQueryM) should be table as below, can those "primary-key" be extracted as Column00 too?

| Column01 | Column02 | Column03 | Column04 | Column05 | Column06 | Column07 | Column08 | Column09 | Column10 | Column11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa |  | 3 |  |  | OK | +4589729222 | testmail01@test.com |  |  | Active |
| aa bbbbb | AAAAAAAAAAA | A |  |  | OK | +123439843933 | testmail01@test.com | CT | false | Active |

Answer (score 0):

See [Expanding All Columns In A Table In Power Query](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot - will try it today and report whether i can declare success :)